# Setting correct baseurl for Jetbrains YouTrack

Tags: 14.04, networking

I've problems setting up YouTrack 2018 on my Ubuntu 14.04 server (managed with plesk). I've download the .zip-version, uploaded and extracted it on my server. Running the installer without browser support, the shown base URL is something like `http://jiffybox...` on port 8080 instead of my domain ([board.my-domain.de](https://board.my-domain.de)).

Is there a way to change the default base URL? I've tried:

```
./youtrack.sh configure --listen-address=board.my-domain.de
```

I want to access youtrack under [board.my-domain.de](https://board.my-domain.de). How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

> I've tried
>
> ```
> ./youtrack.sh configure --listen-address=board.my-domain.de
> ```

Listen address is completely something different than BaseURL.

You need to configure two things:

1. BaseURL
2. ReverseProxy (to change web port)

To do this, please follow official documentation:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Reverse-Proxy-Configuration.html (it contains also information about how to change BaseURL)

Comment: Please do not post answers depending on external links. Put the relevant part into your answer. See [answer] for details.